# Applying for a higher position in the same department

Tags: communication, work-experience, work-life-balance, position

My manager left a few months ago while i just started working in the company for only 3 months. I was then given the opportunities and appointed by my director to learn all the jobs and duties of my manager in order to replace the position while they continue to search for a new candidate for the manager position. I have worked the manager position without any salary increase or given title for 3 months now. I was also given new tasks by my director other than the tasks that were previously handled by my previous manager. I also involved in the development of new plans and system by the company.

My company put up the job advertisement on different job websites for the manager position after my manager left. However, no one seemed to get the position. Until recently I realized that the advertisement was removed and replaced with a new supervisor position job advertisement.

I don't know what should I do? Should I apply for the new supervisor position? I just don't feel good when they placed me in a position that handles a manager/supervisor's jobs but at the same time, did not give me the benefits while searching for new candidate.

*Talked to my director and got my problem solved. I appreciate all the advice given. I know some people were wondering why didn't I ask for extra compensation at the first place. I did not ask for extra compensation because I thought I would only need to help out for a short period of time as told by my director. And as time goes by, I started to like the job more and was thinking of taking the opportunities to learn new things. But after 3 months of working, my passion eventually disappears because I don't see the appreciation in the works I have done and I was also given more works. And yes, I did start to question why didn't I ask for extra compensation at the first place. But there's no point of doing that since it already happened and you can never reverse a time machine. You don't stay at the same place and question yourself, you go forward and learn to solve problems and hopefully learn from your mistakes. To all possible readers, please make sure to provide helpful advice as to how to solve the problem to someone who seeks for your help in the future because there's no point of blaming/questioning them for doing/not doing something. Instead of blaming/questioning, teach them. Thank you!*

Comment: Did you apply for the manager position when it was advertised? Why shouldn't you apply for the supervisor position?

Comment: I did not apply for the manager position when it was advertised because I do not meet the qualifications. It requires at least 5 years working experience. I am still considering if I should apply for the supervisor position because I only started working in this company 6 months ago and I basically only have around 6 months working experience since I graduated and the requirements for a supervisor position advertised is 3-5 years. That's why I am not sure.

Comment: Thank you for posting the link here. I have read that post. I just think my situation is a bit more complicated since I am already working the job as a temporary replacement.

Comment: Have you been given any titles like "Acting Manager"? Are you really doing everything your old manager did? If you've only just started at the company, how do you know?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: @Joanne - I think your situation is easier since you're already working the job. Ask yourself why you didn't ask for additional compensation when given the extra responsibilities in the first place.

Comment: @HorusKol, I have not been given any title. I was only asked to take the duties of my manager. Yes, I do everything my manager did because all the duties I am doing now are included in the job description.

Comment: @JeffO, I did not do that because I thought I would only need to help out for a short period of time as told by my director and would like to take that as a learning opportunity. But things do change as time goes by because that passion can eventually disappears when you don't see the hope while more works are given to you. And yes, I did start to question myself like what you said. But there's no point of doing that since it already happened. You don't stay at the same place and question yourself, you go forward and learn to solve problems and hopefully learn from your mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could think of the 3 months as a chance to have more responsebility and see if it suits you without to big an issue if it didn't.

Since you got more tasks I believe you did fine.

So if this is something you would like to do on a permanent basis check with your director how he feel about you applying for the job. And unless he is negative about it then apply.

Regarding pay / bonus for the 3 months then it should have discussed at the beginning. It can still happen but I think it is less likely.

Comment: "talked to my director and got my problem solved. Thanks a lot for your advice!*